Scrape images into an excel file - Selenium/Pandas/Python
I'm looking to scrape an image from a website into an excel file.
Below is a snippet of my code. This gets the SRC URL and put that into the excel sheet. Is it possible to turn that into the actual image?
if len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#FMP-target'))>0:
    image = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#FMP-target').get_attribute('src')
    print(image)
    images.append(image)
else:
    photo = "No photo"
    print(photo)
    images.append(photo)
driver.quit()

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(images,house_name,description_details,house_price,specs,ratings,cancellation_policy,urls),columns=['Photo','Property Name','Description','Price','Specifications','Ratings','Cancellation Policy','Link'])
df.to_excel(r{file},index=False)

This is the URL
I'm testing with.

Why would you try this with Pandas? That module is for data manipulation, not images.

Is there a better module to use then to imbed the image into the cell?

Retrieve the image(s) and use Openpyxl add_image .

Example to download the images from the site and insert into the Sheet down column A using the image height for cell anchor calculation.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from PIL import Image as Image
from openpyxl import Workbook
import io
from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image as opImage

url = "https://www.airbnb.com.au/rooms/50961691?adults=9&children=2&pets=1&search_mode=regular_search&check_in=2024-12-22&check_out=2024-12-28&source_impression_id=p3_1720759519_P3FseNFXiyBEU7hU&previous_page_section_name=1000&federated_search_id=7f29c222-115b-444d-bcdd-895c3e3151b4"
sheet_row = 1  # Set the row for the image anchor

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
### Get images from Web Site
image_element = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "img")

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

### Add each image found to the Sheet
for img in image_element:
    img_png = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img.screenshot_as_png)).convert("RGB")

    ### Format Image for Openpyxl
    img_stream = io.BytesIO()
    img_png.save(img_stream, format='PNG')
    img_openpyxl = opImage(img_stream)
    print(f"Image Height: {img_openpyxl.height}")

    ### Insert image at Sheet anchor cell
    location = f"A{sheet_row}"
    print(f"Sheet Location: {location}")
    ws.add_image(img_openpyxl, location)

    ### Set next row for image based on last image size
    sheet_row += int(img_openpyxl.height / 19) + 2

wb.save("image.xlsx")

driver.quit()

